# Solving Equation from 3rd degree with unknown coefficients

Tags: equation-solving

I Try to get the simplest  real root for the following equation but I failed

```
eqn1= c1 c2 K1^2 m2 + c2 K1 K2 m2 \[Alpha]1 + c1 K1 K2 m2 \[Delta] - 
   K2^2 m2 \[Alpha]1 \[Delta] + K2^2 T^3 \[Alpha]1 \[Alpha]2 \[Mu]2 + 
   T^2 (-c2 K1 K2 \[Alpha]1 \[Alpha]2 + 
      K2^2 \[Alpha]1 \[Alpha]2 \[Delta] + c1 K1 K2 \[Mu]2 - 
      K2^2 \[Alpha]1 \[Mu]2 + K2^2 m2 \[Alpha]1 \[Alpha]2 \[Mu]2 - 
      K2^2 \[Alpha]1 \[Alpha]2 \[Rho]2) + K2^2 m2 \[Alpha]4 \[Sigma] +
    T (-c1 c2 K1^2 + c2 K1 K2 \[Alpha]1 - 
      c2 K1 K2 m2 \[Alpha]1 \[Alpha]2 + c1 K1 K2 \[Delta] - 
      K2^2 \[Alpha]1 \[Delta] + K2^2 m2 \[Alpha]1 \[Alpha]2 \[Delta] +
       c1 K1 K2 m2 \[Mu]2 - K2^2 m2 \[Alpha]1 \[Mu]2 - 
      c1 K1 K2 \[Rho]2 + K2^2 \[Alpha]1 \[Rho]2 + 
      K2^2 \[Alpha]4 \[Sigma]) == 0;

Solve[{eqn1, 0 < c1 < 1, 0 < c2 < 1, 0 < K1 < 1, k1 < K2 < 1 , 0 < m2 < 1, 
  0 < \[Sigma] < 1, 0 < \[Delta] < \[Sigma], 0 < m2 < 1, 
  0 < \[Rho]2 < m2, 0 < \[Alpha]1 < 1, 
  0 < \[Alpha]2 < \[Alpha]1}, T, Reals]
```

but the result is a huge; can any one give me suggetion ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you confident that a not-huge solution exists?

Comment: by this way no, but maybe there is a method for solving the problem better for that  I asked as lest how to find the run faster?

Comment: Not all the constants are included in the inequalities within `Solve`.  Are the remaining constants real or complex?  Specifying that they are real, if they are, might help.

Comment: Actually, the results have one root real and two are complex. But for my study, the complex term is not important for that I add reals in the code. However, the all constant is positive and less than zero.@bbgodfrey